# If $f$ has a continuous second derivative, prove that $f(x) = f(0) + f'(0) + \int_0^x (x-t)f''(t)dt$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing, alternative-proof

This has been asked before, but I am looking for a proof that does not use integration by parts. Instead, I am looking to use what my textbook called the "Identity Criterion", which states that if the derivative of two functions are equal, then they differ at most by a constant.

Here is what I have thus far:
    By the Second Fundamental Theorem,
    $$f'(x) = \int_0^x f''(t)dt.$$
    Adding something inconspicuous to the right side,
    $$f'(x) = xf''(x) + \int_0^x f''(t)dt - xf''(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \left[ x\int_0^x f''(t)dt - \int_0^x tf''(t)dt \right] = \dfrac{d}{dx} \left[ \int_0^x (x-t)f''(t)dt \right].$$
    By the Identity Criterion, $f(x)$ and $\int_0^x (x-t)f''(t)dt$ must only differ by a constant.
    But by the First Fundamental Theorem, $$\int_0^x (x-t)f''(t)dt = $$

This is where I start to lose the plot. Any guidance would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

There is  mistake in your formula. The second term is $xf'(0)$ instead of $f'(0)$.

Let $F(x)=\int_0^{x} (x-t)f''(t)dt=x\int_0^{x} f''(t)dt-\int_0^{x} tf''(t)dt$. Then $F'(x)=\int_0^{x} f''(t)dt+xf''(x)-xf''(x)$ by product rule for differentiation. Hence $F'(x)=f'(x)-f'(0)$. Hence $F(x)-f(x)+xf'(0)$ has derivative $0$ which implies it is a constant. Put $x=0$ to see that $c=-f(0)$. This gives $F(x)=f(x)+f(0)-xf'(0)$. This gives the desired identity.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just integration by parts?

\begin{align*}
f(x)-f(0)&=\int_{0}^{x}f'(t)dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{x}-\dfrac{d}{dt}(x-t)f'(t)dt\\
&=-(x-t)f'(t)\bigg|_{t=0}^{t=x}+\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)f''(t)dt\\
&=xf'(0)+\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)f''(t)dt.
\end{align*}

**Edit:**

Let 
\begin{align*}
\varphi(x)&=f(x)-\left(f(0)+f'(0)x+\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)f''(t)dt\right)\\
\varphi'(x)&=f'(x)-f'(0)-\int_{0}^{x}f''(t)dt-xf''(x)+xf''(x)\\
\varphi'(x)&=f'(x)-f'(0)-(f'(x)-f'(0))\\
\varphi'(x)&=0,
\end{align*}
and so $\varphi(x)=c$, but $\varphi(0)=0$ and hence $c=0$.

Comment: Because integration by parts has not be covered by this point in the textbook, so it cannot be used in a proof.

Comment: In the second line of your edit, why did you maintain the integral?

Comment: That is a part of the product rule.